# Solution Templates in VS2010

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2010

I have heard it said that, unlike VS2008, VS2010 will support  Solution templates in addition to item and project templates.  However, the SolutionTemplates directory contains only a "blank.sln", so it's difficult to draw any inferences about what is supposed to go in there.

Has anyone seen any documentation about how to create a solution template?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything on creating a Solution template, but have you checked out [How to: Create Multi-Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?